# Power over the centuries: spiritual vs. political vs. economic

Tags: economy, religion, political-history

I recently attended a presentation on the shift in power over the centuries. The speaker argued that ...

- the power in the middle ages was in the churches, i.e., the priests and, thus, in the spiritual centers
- in contrast, in the 17th century there was a shift towards the political centers, i.e., the palaces and the kings and princes, alter also a shift towards democratic institutions
- nowadays, he argued, the power lies in the economical forces, i.e. the businesses and their CEOs

I suppose that this theory was taken from somewhere, but even with extensive research I could not find any sources for it.

Have you ever heard of a similar theory?

Comment: It's a common enough opinion, with similar sentiments in everything from political theory books to science-fiction.  I don't know of any single source for the idea, but I don't know that the presenter necessarily needed to have one.  It might just be a casual analysis of historical trends.

Comment: [Merchant, Soldier, Sage](http://www.amazon.com/Merchant-Soldier-Sage-History-Castes/dp/1594203105)

Comment: Michael Mann - Sources of Social Power

Answer (score 4):

I am considering this a reference request for seminal works on "power" in historiography.

The most well known recent theorist of "power" as a historical determinant is Foucault.  In Foucault's work power seems to be organised by a historical context of possibilities of knowledge, an "episteme," that orders how people perceive and enact power.  I do not believe that Foucault's conclusions about the organisation of past societies matches your speaker's: Foucault's concept of power is much more developed.  Additionally, many historians blanch at the lack of traditional historiography backing Foucault's conclusions.